# org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException in Gradle while building

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, build-tools, gradle-eclipse

I am not able to build Gradle project in my OSX and getting below error due to 
`org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException`.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.defaultDependencies(Lorg/gradle/api/Action;)Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration;
```

Project was building properly earlier and I have not changed anything recently. My system has HomeBrew Gradle 2.2.1 installed.

**build.gadle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

buildscript {
repositories {  
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'http://artifactory.xxxxtech.net/artifactory/libs-release'
        }
    }
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.xxxxx.tap.trap:gradle-plugin:1.0.0-rc-20161012063525'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'trap'

trap {
    sut project.name
    url = 'http://elasticsearch.tap.xxxx.xxxxtech.org'
    owner = 'AFW'
    framework = 'JUnit'
    environment = 'ci'
    timeZone = 'CET'
}

task unitTrapSend(type: com.xxxxx.tap.trap.TrapSend) {
    input = "testresults/"
    category 'unit'
}

finalizedBy unitTrapSend
```

**Error**

```
Concurs-MacBook-Pro-9:MochaTrap navanithh$ gradle build --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/navanithh/Documents/MochaTrap/build.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MochaTrap'.
> org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.defaultDependencies(Lorg/gradle/api/Action;)Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration;

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MochaTrap'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.defaultDependencies(Lorg/gradle/api/Action;)Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration;
    at com.concur.tap.trap.TrapPlugin.apply(TrapPlugin.java:21)
    at com.concur.tap.trap.TrapPlugin.apply(TrapPlugin.java:11)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultPluginContainer.java:188)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultPluginContainer.java:137)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.apply(DefaultPluginContainer.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:115)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:131)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$apply$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_dx9dpjw5aj1pgm28nq8ovanex.run(/Users/navanithh/Documents/MochaTrap/build.gradle:16)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    ... 32 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.795 secs
```

Comment: Please include the full error by adding the command arg `--stacktrace` and add your `build.gradle` file.  Right now it's impossible to answer

Comment: @JBirdVegas - Updated question with build file and error trace. Please look in to it and advice.

Comment: Seems you are attempting to make some problematic call in the `trap` gradle plugin.  This line `at com.concur.tap.trap.TrapPlugin.apply(TrapPlugin.java:21)`  What are you calling on this line?  Whatever it is the method does not exist at runtime.